# jQuery find and prev methods

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML form on which I am running jQuery "find" method to find a specific set of elements. One type of elements I want to find have to fulfil these two criteria:

- Input of type text
- The DOM element following it directly has a specific class ("error")

In the example form below, the first div (select in calendar-dropdown) would be found, the second one ("ignore") would not and the third one would.

```
<form>
    <div class="calendar-dropdown">
        <select>
            // options
        </select>
    </div>

    <input type="text" value="one">
    <div class="ignore">Ignored</div>

    <input type="text" value="one">
    <div class="error">Show error</div>
</form>
```

My current find method looks like this:

```
form.find('.calendar-dropdown select, :text:visible.next(.error)')
```

The calendar dropdown is there to find another set of elements that I also need to process. I am aware that this solution is wrong, but I don't know how to make it work. Is this possible to be done using the find method?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.filter` to get all of the inputs then filter to the ones that you do want:

```
$("input").filter((i, e) => $(e).next(".error").length != 0)
```

> In the example, the first div would not be found, but the second one would [be found]

```js
$("input")
  .filter((i, e) => $(e).next(".error").length != 0)
  .addClass("inputError")
```

```css
.inputError {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" value="one">
  <div class="ignore">Ignored</div>

  <input type="text" value="two">
  <div class="error">Show error</div>
</form>
```

---

Note: `.find` does not have an equivalent callback/selector-function to be applied.

You can add custom selectors eg `:hasnext` but if `.filter` covers you, it's overly complicated.

You can also use `.add` to combine multiple selectors after they have been filtered.

Comment: I tried using .add, but that discard the elements returned by the .find part. With code ".find('.calendar-dropdown select').add('.a-alert-inline-error').prev(':text:visible')", only the elements found by the '.add' part are returned.

Comment: You'll need to clarify / update your question as there's no `.calendar-dropdown` in your HTML - this answers the question as asked.

Answer (score 0):

`prev` and `next` filter not available. Try using `prev()` method

```js
console.log($('form').find(':text + .error').prev(':text').get())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <input type="text" value="one">
    <div class="ignore">Ignored</div>

    <input type="text" value="two">
    <div class="error">Show error</div>
</form>
```

Comment: I updated the HTML form to include also another element I want to grab. Your solution would discard the calendar-dropdown element, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Might consider using `.each()`:

```
$("input[type='text']", form).each(function(i, el){
  if($(el).next().is(".error")){
    // Do the needful
  }
});
```

This will iterate each of the inputs in `form` and only perform an action on those that have `.error` as the next element.

Otherwise consider a different selector: https://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-selector/

```
$("input[type='text'] + .error", form).css("border-color", "red");
```